# How to do equality check of array values and keys from another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two diff array and I want to print these array based on equal condition.

**First array**

```
     Array ( 
            [0] => fname 
            [1] => lname 
            [2] => email  
      )
```

**Second array**

```
   Array ( 
           [fname] => john 
           [lname] => notdefined 
           [email] => xyz@gmail.com 
           [address] => london 
    )
```

Now my problem is I want to print values from **second array** if and only if this array's index match with **first array** values...

**Second array's index == first array's value** (I can say this is equality condition for better understanding)

In this case my output should be

```
   Array (
           [fname] => john
           [lname] => notdefined
           [email] => xyz@gmail.com
      )
```

It should not display address because in **first array** is not present...

Here this is just sample code but in reality I have a very big array with some additional info also.

Comment: Flip your first array with `array_flip` and then make use of `array_intersect_key` on the two arrays.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran your suggestion worked like charm bro... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways, one of them is:

```
foreach($secArr as $key => $val)
{
     if(in_array($key, $firstArr))
         echo $val;
}
```

or:

```
$keys = array_flip($firstArr);
$arr = array_intersect_key($secArr, $keys);
//display $arr;
```

or:

```
foreach($firstArr as $key)
{
     if($secArr[$key])
         echo $secArr[$key];
}
```

Comment: worked like charm with foreach ways.. need to test array_flip

Answer (score 1):

Swap first array key and value using [array_flip](https://www.php.net/array_flip) function and Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison using [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'fname',1 => 'lname' ,2 => 'email');
$array1 = array_flip($array1);
$array2 = array( 
       'fname' => 'john', 
       'lname' => 'notdefined', 
       'email' => 'xyz@gmail.com', 
       'address' => 'london' 
    );

$new = array_intersect_key($array2,$array1);
print_r($new);
```

<kbd>[working demo](https://3v4l.org/Rq3Ga)</kbd>